# Ubuntu suspends itself a few seconds after waking up

Tags: suspend

Running 21.04 on a Razer Blade Base early-2020

When I wake up my laptop from sleep, it will automatically suspend itself about 20-30 seconds later with no warning.  This is while it's plugged in.

How can I prevent this or figure out why?

Comment: Curious is this the razer blade 14?

Comment: @ClassicStyle no this is the blade 15 base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this on 20.04 with the following kernel parameter:
button.lid_init_state=open

But this does not work for 21.04 as far as I've tried.

Comment: This actually does work in 21.04 for me at least.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @vityobugs answer, this issue has been addressed here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RazerBlade

The OS does not detect that the lid has been opened if the laptop is suspended. This can be fixed through the following modification:

1. Edit the default grub config:

```
    sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

2. Add `button.lid_init_state=open` to the end of the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` option, like this:

   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash button.lid_init_state=open"
3. Run the following command to update grub when you are done:

```
   sudo update-grub
   sudo reboot
```